# Using dynamic multi-dimensional arrays in c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am making a C++ program that checks if given aray is a [latin square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square). I need to use a dynamic multi-dimensional array that stores given latin square. But I cant pass the array to a function that does the checking...

Currently I have such code for calling the function:

```
int squaretest(int **p, int n, int sum) {

    //some code
};
```

And this code is for creating the array:

```
int main() { 

    //some code. n - length of one row, sum - sum of elements in one row.
    int a;  
    int **lsquare;
    lsquare = new int*[n];
    for (int i=0;i<=n-1;i++) for (int j=0;j<=n-1;j++) {
        cin >>a;
        lsquare[i][j] = a;
    }
    blocktest(lsquare,n,sum);
    //some code
};
```

The code compiles (i am using Geany IDE and G++ compiler) but when I run it in terminal, after the first imput, that has to be stored in block[0][0] I get *Segmentation fault* error. What's wrong with my code and what is the correct sollution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be able to do that.. You actually need to do this:

```
int **lsquare = new int*[n];

for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    lquare[i] = new int[n];

for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        cin >> lsquare[i][j];

blocktest(lsquare,n,sum);
```

The better system would be to do:

```
int *lsquare = new int[n*n];

for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    for (int j=0; j<n; ++j)
        cin >> lsquare[i + j*n];

blocktest(lsquare, n, sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to allocate memory for second dimension of the matrix.

```
int **lsquare;
lsquare = new int*[n];
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i){
  lsquare[i] = new int[n];
....}
```

nobody  writes

```
for (int i=0;i<=n-1;i++){...}
```

Do instead

```
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of pointers in lsquare.

You might want to just do something like:

```
lsquare = new int[n * n];
```

That way you can then fill in this square, but the type is then:

```
int *lsquare
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually creating an array of arrays.  Not only do you need to allocate the array of arrays using `new`, but also you must allocate all `n` arrays.  You'll want to have the outer loop of your nested for loop allocate each of the n sub-arrays.

```
lsquare = new int*[n];
for (int i=0;i<=n-1;i++) 
{
    lsquare[i] = new int[n];
    for (int j = 0;j<=n-1;j++)
    {
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

You made yourself a pointer pointer that can be used as a matrix, allocated one row for it, then proceeded to act like you'd allocated an entire n*n matrix. You will indeed get a segfault if you run that.

You need to allocate enough space for n*n elements, not just n of them.

A less error-prone solution might be to use a std::vector of std::vectors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate space for the second dimension too, add this after you allocate lsquare:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    lsquare[i] = new int[n];
}
```